# пространственные операторы и функции в Oracle

Tags: oracle, spatial

Пытаюсь вычислить время выполнения пространственных запросов в Oracle и PostgreSQL.

Результат кардинально различается. PostgreSQL выполняет запросы в сотни раз быстрее. Причина мне не ясна.

к примеру. запрос PostgreSQL:

```
select count(ST_Intersection(t.gdo_geometry, w.gdo_geometry)) from table1 t, table2 w
```

oracle:

```
select count(SDO_GEOM.SDO_INTERSECTION(t. gdo_geometry, w.gdo_geometry, 1)) from table1 t, table2 w
```

Разница, повторюсь, существенная. Причина не ясна.

Некто знающий человек сделал замечание, мол использование пространственных ФУНКЦИЙ в Oracle - это ошибка. И данные функции не используюсь индексов. Правильным решением по мнению этого человека использованием пространственных ОПЕРАТОРОВ. Дескать операторы используют индекс.

Я не базовик и разграничение на операторы и функции для меня, признаться, стало откровением.

2 вопроса:

1) почему такая большая разница во времени выполнения запросов между разными СУБД?

2) насколько замечание про операторы и функции адекватно?

Answer (score 1):

Так как Вам никто не ответил ничего за 4 недели, подкину пару заметок:

- любое поведение может быть объяснено только заглядыванием "вовнутрь" процесса - т.е. включайте трассировку и смотрите, на что тратится время, почему оптимизатор принимает решение брать или не брать тот или иной индекс и т.д.
- вообще Oracle Spatial не самая, скажем так, популярная технология, поэтому получить квалифицированную консультацию можно попробовать на sql.ru и oraclegis.ru (Александр Рындин, на sql.ru он закрывает добрую половину всех вопросов по MDSYS)
- мысль про "операторы" и "функции" комментировать не стану
- если нужна помощь с трассировками и анализом результатов - говорите

Comment: Благодарю за ваши заметки

> Странно а что может быть популярней Oracle Spatial? Если используется Oracle, значит для работы с пространственными объектами используется Oracle Spatial. или я не прав?

> За прошедшее время, я кое чего выяснил, дело в том что Oracle Spatial имеет много различных функций. И получается так что есть некоторые функции которые выдают одинаковый результат. Зачем подобное дублирование я сказать не могу. Но уверен разработчикам виднее. На практике эти функции имеют разный план выполнения, а следовательно и разное время исполнения.

Comment: Добавлю что с PostgreSQL такая же ситуация. Разные функции - разный план выполнения - разное время, но при этом одинаковый результат.

Comment: Я Spatial даже краем глаза не видел, так что ответить мне нечего. Предположу лишь, возможно есть два подхода, как и во многих других примерах работы с БД - когда база и хранит данные и обрабатывает их (т.е. бизнес-логика реализована на стороне БД) - и когда база только хранит данные, а вся "математика" вынесена за пределы - на уровень сервера приложений например. Так вот, может в случае с гео-данными, "принято" идти первым путем, да еще и не использовать типы данных, предназначенные специально для гео-данных. А может просто процент использующих Oracle и гео ничтожно мал. Не знаю в общем.